# Python Pandas - loc create fortran ordered numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

For example:

```
nrow = 10
ncol= 10
a = np.arange(nrow*ncol,dtype=np.int32).reshape(nrow,ncol)
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
ix_list = np.arange(nrow,dtype=np.int32)

print np.isfortran(a.values) #  False
print np.isfortran(a.loc[ix_list,:].values) #  True
```

Why is .loc create pandas dataframe with fortran ordered numpy array? Can I force it to create pandas dataframe with C ordered numpy array?

Comment: What's the `shape` of this `loc` produced array? Its `flags`?

Comment: Do you mean shape of ndarray from a.loc[ix_list,:]? it has same shape as a, which is (10,10) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer to your first question but calling `.values` on your dataframe will return a numpy ndarray so:

- To check if the array is fortran, as written in the doc, you should better use numpy alternative `.flags.f_contiguous` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isfortran.html)
- To force your ndarray use `np.ascontiguousarray()`
  or `np.asfortranarray()`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was finding a way of forcing .loc to create C ordered ndarray directly for performance issue. np.ascontiguousarray() is slow when it is used with larger size of fortran ordered ndarray.

Comment: Ok, can you please share your findings?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I couldn't find such way.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just in case, what about transposing your array? using a.loc[ix_list,:].transpose().values for instance ?

Comment: Just another question, why do you need to use .loc ? Is it possible for you to just use df selection like : a[ix_list].values

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. a.loc[ix_list,:].transpose().values give C ordered ndarray, but I need ndarray from .loc, not transpose. a[ix_list].values works, but  a[ix_list].values and a.loc[id_list:] return different pandas dataframe generally since a[ix_list] is about selecting columns and a.loc[id_list:] is about selecting index.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [423]: adf = pd.DataFrame(a)
In [424]: ix_list = np.arange(nrow,dtype=np.int32)
```

Your problem indexing creates a F ordered array, as seen in `flags` and `strides`.  This is what I expect to see when doing `transpose` on an ordinary numpy array.

```
    In [426]: adf.loc[ix_list].values.flags
    Out[426]: 
      C_CONTIGUOUS : False
      F_CONTIGUOUS : True
      OWNDATA : False
      WRITEABLE : True
      ALIGNED : True
      UPDATEIFCOPY : False
    In [427]: adf.loc[ix_list].values.strides
    Out[427]: (4, 40)
```

But other `loc` indexing produces a C order array:

```
In [428]: adf.loc[:].values.flags
Out[428]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ....
In [429]: adf.loc[ix_list[::2]].values.flags
Out[429]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ...
In [430]: adf.loc[ix_list[:-2]].values.flags
Out[430]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ...
```

That looks a bug in the `pandas` `loc` indexer.

I'm guessing that `np.ascontiguousarray` is the cheapest way to ensure all cases are C ordered, since it does a `np.array(..., copy=False)`, which is a conditional `copy`.  Arrays that are already `C` won't make a copy.

In quick time tests, adding a `copy` or `np.ascontiguousarray` does not slow things down at all.

```
In [439]: timeit np.ascontiguousarray(adf.loc[ix_list].values).flags
514 µs ± 7.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [440]: timeit adf.loc[ix_list].values.copy().flags
509 µs ± 5.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [441]: timeit adf.loc[ix_list].values.flags
513 µs ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [442]: timeit adf.loc[:].values.flags
24.9 µs ± 11.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [443]: timeit np.ascontiguousarray(adf.loc[:].values).flags
30 µs ± 865 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [444]: timeit adf.loc[ix_list[:-1]].values.flags
559 µs ± 12.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [445]: timeit np.ascontiguousarray(adf.loc[ix_list[:-1]].values).flags
559 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Selecting rows on the numpy array is considerably faster than using `loc`:

```
In [446]: timeit adf.loc[:].values[ix_list].flags
32.9 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [447]: timeit adf.values[ix_list].flags
20.9 µs ± 1.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```